# Rotating teams without repeating

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

I have 24 teams that will rotate to 12 stations (2 teams per station) Teams will not compete against another team more than once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotating teams through stations](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51743/rotating-teams-through-stations)

Comment: Not clear.  What it the question?

Comment: Instructions unclear. Rotated station and it is now upside down.

Comment: This team builder is for 24 teams. I have 12 stations for the teams to rotate through. There will be 2 teams competing at each station. How do i rotate all of the teams through all of the stations competing against  teams only once.

Comment: Can one team visit the same station multiple times? And how many matches does each team need to play?  Also, please see the question that I linked in my earlier comment, because yours is very similar and it may provide an answer for you.

Comment: I guess like 6 years ago now, my school had a field day competition with 20 teams, each visiting 10 stations. We wanted it so every team visited every station, but no two teams ever competed against each other twice, which sounds basically the same as yours, but never figured it out. I've learned a lot since then, so might be able to find something, but at the time was most of the way through a proof that it was impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I got this trick from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring#Examples.

Number the teams 1 to 24. Arrange teams 1 to 23 evenly spaced on the circumference of a circle, and place team 24 in the center.

On the $i$th round, for $i$ = 1, 2, ..., 23, have team 24 play against team $i$. For the other teams, divide them into pairs so that in each pair, the line connecting the two teams is perpendicular to the line connecting team $i$ to team 24. This means that team i – 1 plays i + 1, team i – 2 plays i + 2, and so on, where addition is modulo 23.

Comment: This ensures that every team plays every other team exactly once, but it makes no guarantee about how many times each team plays at each station...